# local convert=string.char

Tags: lua

What is the use of this line. I'm new for LUA programming char LUA.

```
code=55
local convert=string.char(4,1,0,0,0,0,math.floor(224 + (code/16)), code % 16)
print(convert)
```

here-`string.character` inside using  `(4,1,0,0,0,0,0)` what is purpose this using.

Comment: you can read a manual first to see what `string.char` does

Answer (score 0):

The char function converts an ASCII-number to a string value, see [lua string library](http://lua-users.org/wiki/StringLibraryTutorial).

> string.char(i1, i2, ...)
>
> Generate a string representing the character codes passed as arguments. Numerical codes are not necessarily portable across platforms.
>
> ```
> > = string.char(65,66,67)
> ABC
> > = string.char()  -- empty string
> ```

Comment: here (4,1,0,0,0,0). what is the use

Comment: looks like a control characters sequence, but don't know where ur snippet is from